# Approximate a function around a given point

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, approximation

I am given the function of $x(t) = \frac{x_0 e^{t}}{1+x_0(e^t-1)}$, and asked how it behaves around $0$. The solution says the $x_0(e^t-1)$ on the denominator is negligible so the function is approximated as the numerator $x(t) \simeq x_0e^{t}$ and it behaves like a exponential function around $0$.

However, can I also argue that $e^t \approx 1$ (which is used to neglect the term $x_0(e^t-1)$ on the numerator), so the whole function becomes $x_0$ around $0$? What's the problem of doing this and is there a general rule or trick that I should follow when approximating a function(evaluate the function's behavior) around a given point?

Thank you in advance for your help!

William

Comment: It all depend on how good an approximation you want to make. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cow

Comment: How to determine a good approximation then? In this case, if I also simplify the numerator, the function will behave like a constant around 0, which is obviously not accurate, isn't it?

I take the derivative of the original function and it's $\frac{1}{x_0} + 1$ at zero. However, a constant has zero derivative at 0 and the approximated exponential $x_0(e^t)$ has a derivative of $x_0$ at zero, which is also far away from the actual derivative. How can I determine which approximation is better?

Comment: If you just want a simple approximation, I would just use a linear one. $e^t\approx 1+t$. Then for the denominator, if $x_0$ is small, $$\frac1{1+x_0t}\approx 1-x_0t$$I then get rid of terms in $t^2$. Therefore $x(t)\approx x_0+(x_0-x_0^2)t$ (if I did not make any mistakes)

Comment: I am actually asking how to determine if an approximation is reasonable enough. Are all these approximations reasonable but with different extent of abstractions(loss of information)? How to argue that one approximation is better than the other one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the area of function approximation, you need to define what you want to preserve.

Taking your case, suppose that we want to preserve the exponential trend. So, write for example
$$x(t) = \frac{x_0 e^{t}}{1+x_0(e^t-1)} = \frac{x_0+x_0 (e^{t}-1)}{1+x_0(e^t-1)}$$and define $y(t)=e^{t}-1$ to make
$$x(t)=\frac{x_0+x_0 \,y(t)}{1+x_0\,y(t)}$$ and work around $y(t)=0$. By Taylor, we then  have
$$x(t)=x_0+x_0(1-x_0) \,y(t)+\cdots$$ that is to say
$$x(t)=x_0^2+x_0(1-x_0)\,  e^t$$ which is not exactly $x_0\, e^t$.

For illustration purposes, I shall use $x_0=\pi$ and say that we want to look at the behaviour for $-0.1 \leq t \leq 0.1$. As a comparison tool, let us compute the two $L^2$ norms
$$\Phi_1=\int_{-0.1}^{+0.1} \Bigg[\frac{\pi e^{t}}{1+\pi(e^t-1)}-\pi e^t\Bigg]^2\,dt= 7.01\times 10^{-2}$$
$$\Phi_2=\int_{-0.1}^{+0.1} \Bigg[\frac{\pi e^{t}}{1+\pi(e^t-1)}-\left(\pi^2 +\pi(1-\pi)\,e^t\right)\Bigg]^2\,dt=2.01\times 10^{-3}$$ So $\Phi_1\sim 35\Phi_2$.

Which one do you prefer ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

So it depends on what properties and to what extent of the function I want to preserve/analyze? The solution they gave as $\pi e^t$ is one way to approximate but it's not as good as the one you gave, is it correct?

And the quality of approximation can be evaluated by the difference between the approximated function and the original one?

Comment: @WilliamLin. This is a vast domain (I already spent more than 60 years working it for professional reasons in industry). Yes, to me, $x_0\,e^t} is very bad. A good criteria to compare approximations is the integral norm over the region over which you want to use the approximation.